# How to call a stored procedure with hibernate reactive?

Tags: quarkus-reactive

I'm looking for a way to call a stored procedure with an output parameter using hibernate's reactive api (ReactiveConnectionSupplier).

For example:

```sql
create procedure uspSum (
  @param1     int,
  @param2     int,
  @result     int output
)
as
begin
    set @result = @param1 + @param2
    
    return @result
end

Declare @r int
exec uspSum 5, 7, @r output
select @r
```

Could someone help me with an example?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.